# Why am I getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException using Stack in Java?

Tags: java, collections, iterator, stack

I'm getting a concurrent modification exception despite using an iterator with a stack

```
package samplecodes;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;

public class ReOrderStack {






    public static Stack<Integer> reorder(Stack<Integer> s )
    {
        Queue <Integer> q= new LinkedList<Integer>();

        if(s==null|| s.isEmpty())
            return s;
        // Use an iterator to prevent concurrent modification exception!

        Iterator<Integer> it = s.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Integer val= it.next();// concurrent modification exception!
            if(val>=0)
            {
                s.remove(val);
                q.add(val);
            }
        }

    //we've inspected the stack

    //add back from the queue to stack
    while(!q.isEmpty())
    {
        Integer val=q.remove();

        s.push(val);
    }
        return s;

    }
}
```

Any thoughts why?

Comment: You have to do the removal through the iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Stack.remove` is not safe. It occurs `ConcurrentModificationException` with `Iterator`. To avoid `ConcurrentModificationException` use `Iterator.remove()`.
 Try,

```
Iterator<Integer> it = s.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Integer val= it.next();          
        if(val>=0)
        {
            it.remove(); //Use Iterator.remove
            //s.remove(val);
            q.add(val);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cant believe  I missed that! Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify stack while iterating. You must remove line `s.remove()` to prevent this error from occurring. It happens because iterator had a copy which is now different from original. If you want to remove ever element and add to queue, you could use following code:

```
while(!s.empty()) {
    val = s.pop();
    if(val>=0) {
        q.add(val);
    }
}
```